# You tube Search API - Video Id Prefix with '-' sign?

Tags: youtube

Few video Ids are prefixed with '-' sign. When we search these Id's with prefix on Youtube, it says no records found. However, Youtube is able to play these videos.

Eg:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xYmfZ2Ic_M  (Video will play)
- https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=-xYmfZ2Ic_M (No results
  found).

I would like to know: what all characters could come as prefix so that I can allow or remove them before my Youtube API call? Or is there any standard way to handle this thing?

Answer (score 0):

You refer to 'API call' using the URL is not making a API call, its calling the search URL. The URL unfortunatly does not work using a URL encoded parameter.

I suggest to implement this using YouTube API V3. In PHP this correctly retrives the video based on a ID even if it starts with hyphens. I have provided a PHP snippet below...

```
//In PHP
function videosListById($service, $part, $params) {
$params = array_filter($params);
$response = $service->videos->listVideos(
    $part,
    $params
);

print_r($response);
}

videosListById($service,
'snippet,contentDetails,statistics', 
array('id' => '-xYmfZ2Ic_M'));
```

To see this in action you can visit the following URL;
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?id=-xYmfZ2Ic_M&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics